# Fast, non-ajax (I guess) updating information

Tags: websocket, phpwebsocket

I'm looking forward to know how they do this. They update their information on just a couple of ms and I see no AJAX requests on my firebug console.

Here is the page: [Económico](http://economico.sapo.pt/noticias/edp-contraataca-leilao-da-deco-com-nova-oferta-de-luz-e-gas_169111.html)

As you can see on this two images below, this is the information they are updating.
[image][image]

Thanks for your help, looking forward to extend my knowledge!

Comment: i see xhr streaming in my chrome->network tabs

Comment: i see websockets in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are making requests using [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

e.g.

```
Request URL:ws://ortc-prd2-useast1-s0002.realtime.co/broadcast/444/m38tirp9/websocket
Request Method:GET
```

The responses are in Frames

So not your usual stuff, what firebug are you using? It is likely not reported in the console, but in the Network tab.

Comment: Hmm, guess I'll have to look into websockets! Thanks for the link. I'm using Firebug 1.11.3 :)

Comment: After looking a bit into the link you gave me, what PHP framework would you suggest? Or would you suggest anything else that is compatible with PHP? Thanks :)

Comment: You will need a websocket server which you can do with php, node,js and some others. Then to communicate with this it is purely frontend (html5/javascript). Have a look at this - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets) websockets are not supported by IE<10. How does it degrades? [edit] after searching a bit, I found that I need something like Long Polling :)

Comment: websockets is a brand new HTML5 tech that is usually only used in experiments, or internal apps where you know you can enforce everyone to use the latest chrome for example (e.g. internal stock exchange for a bank). Otherwise it will get very expensive/time consuming because you will have to have a websocket server and the code for that, and then a traditional method using javascript HTTP requests.

Comment: do a google search for "websockets with http fallback" e.g. https://code.google.com/p/jquery-graceful-websocket/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll read up the useful information you gave me!!

Answer (score 1):

That's done using [**WebSocket**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets).

Look at the network tab in chrome dev tools and you'll see it.

Comment: Hmm, guess I'll have to look into websockets! Thanks for the link.

Comment: you just see the ws:// link in firebug/chrome dev tools - after that (once the websocket connection is established) you need a sniffer like wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

They are using Realtime.co, which I work for. It's a full-blown real-time communication platform that handle all the nasty stuff for you: scalability, security and automatic fallbacks when a browser does not support websocket.

You can get your own free account at Realtime.co and give it a go. You'll start doing your own cool real-time enabled applications in not time.